# Mean time to sharded data being unavailable in a distributed storage system

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

How do I model time to data unavailability given the following parameters?  Data unavailability means that every machine that hosts a replica of data is down at the same time.  All replicas for a single piece of data exist in a single cell on different machines.

- $n$ - number of machines.  A machine exists in exactly 1 cell.
- $c$ - the number of cells.  A cell is a group of machines.  Assume each cell contains the same number of machines.
- $f$ - mean time to failure of an individual machine.
- $r$ - the number of replicas for each piece of data.  If data is replicated twice, it exists on 2 separate machines in the same cell.
- $d$ - the number of pieces of data in the system.  Data is uniformly distributed across cells and each cell uniformly distributes data across machines.
- $t$ - the recovery time for a machine after it fails.

For example, I might have:

- $n$ = 100 machines
- $c$ = 5 cells each containing 20 machines.
- $f$ = 6 months is the mean time to failure for a machine.
- $r$ = 2, data is replicated twice in the same cell on different machines.
- $d$ = 1000 pieces of data. Meaning each cell has 200 pieces and each machine has 10 pieces.
- $t$ = 1 week to recover a failed machine.

The [Availability in Globally Distributed Storage Systems](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/36737.pdf) paper suggests an exponential distribution might work.

> The exponential distribution is a reasonable approximation for the following reasons. First, the
>   Weibull distribution is a generalization of the exponential distribution that allows the rate parameter to increase
>   over time to reflect the aging of disks. In a large population of disks, the mixture of disks of different ages
>   tends to be stable, and so the average failure rate in a
>   cell tends to be constant. When the failure rate is stable,
>   the Weibull distribution provides the same quality of fit
>   as the exponential. Second, disk failures make up only
>   a small subset of failures that we examined, and model
>   results indicate that overall availability is not particularly
>   sensitive to them. Finally, other authors ([24]) have concluded that correlation and non-homogeneity of the recovery rate and the mean time to a failure event have
>   a much smaller impact on system-wide availability than
>   the size of the event

Comment: If you want mean time to unavailability of a specific piece of data, then IMHO $n$ and $c$ don't matter because that piece of data doesn't care how many other machines exist -- it just cares about the $r=2$ machines it's hosted on.  Is that what you want?  Alternatively, if you want mean time to _some_ data (i.e. _any_ data) becoming unavailable, then $n,c$ matter but it matters even more how many distinct pieces of data there are in your universe, and how they are distributed onto the $n$ machines.

Comment: Thanks, it's *some* piece of data.  I'll add another variable $d$ for number of pieces of data which is uniformly distributed among cells and each cell uniformly distributes data per machine.

Comment: "uniform" distrib is probably not optimal (though it might be realistic in your actual application).  if "uniform" then any pair of intra-cluster machines down at the same time would (probably) lead to some data being unavailable if $d$ is large.  however, if you pair up the machines first, then there are many cases you can survive $\ge 2$ machines failing in the same cluster.  (the downside is: if a machine-pair fails, then _many_ pieces of data will be down.  but if your criterion is mean time to unavail. of some piece of data, then many being down still just counts as one event.)

Comment: Yep, that's one of the areas I wanted to model.  Currently, data distribution is uniform so you're correct that it's highly likely with a large $d$ that if any machine-pair in a cell (i.e. cluster) goes down, we'll have data unavailable.  I'd love to explore how different distributions affect mean time to data unavailable (and also number of data unavailable per outage) but I wanted to keep the question narrow enough to digest as there's already 6 variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a monte carlo simulation to model the problem because I didn't know how to do it analytically.  Graphs at the bottom.

Python code: https://github.com/jschaf/cellarch

The simulation works as follows:

- Partition NUM_MACHINES into NUM_PARTITIONS separate groups.  This simulation
  uses partition to refer to separate groups instead of `cell` used by the math
  StackExchange question.
- Uniformly distribute NUM_DATA pieces of data to all subsets of machines such
  that:

  1. Every subset of machines reside in the same partition.
  2. Every subset has exactly a size of NUM_REPLICAS.
- Generate machine failure start times pulling samples from an exponential
  distribution.
- Get the cumulative sum of the failure times to generate subsequent failure
  times for a machine.  Meaning, turn [1, 3, 2, 7] into [1, 4, 6, 13].
- Create an outage for a machine by adding the time to repair to the failure
  start time.  The time to repair is drawn from a normal distribution.  Meaning, 
  assuming we draw time `R` from the normal distribution turn `[1, 4, 6, 13]` into 
  `[(1, 1 + R1), (4, 4 + R2), (6, 6 + R3), (13, 13 + R4)]`
- Find all outages where N machines are down at the same time.  This is an
  outage clique.  When N == NUM_REPLICAS, this means we might have an outage
  for some subset of data.
- Find all outage cliques where each machine in the clique hosts the same
  piece of data.  The found cliques mean some data is completely unavailable.
- Run the above steps many times to get the time to first data unavailability.

[image: Outages with a MTTF up to 60 months]
[image: Outages with a MTTF up to 30 months]
[image: Outages by partition]